# NEST: How to query against multiple indices and handle different subclasses (document types)?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I’m playing around with ElasticSearch in combination with NEST in my C# project. My use case includes several indices with different document types which I query separately so far. Now I wanna implement a global search function which queries against all existing indices, document types and score the result properly.

So my question: How do I accomplish that by using NEST?

Currently I’m using the function `SetDefaultIndex` but how can I define multiple indices?

Maybe for a better understanding, this is the query I wanna realize with NEST:

```
{
  "query": {
    "indices": {
      "indices": [
        "INDEX_A",
        "INDEX_B"
      ],
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "FIELD": "VALUE"
        }
      },
      "no_match_query": {
        "term": {
          "FIELD": "VALUE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can explicitly tell NEST to use multiple indices:

```cs
client.Search<MyObject>(s=>s
    .Indices(new [] {"Index_A", "Index_B"})
    ...
)
```

If you want to search across all indices

```cs
client.Search<MyObject>(s=>s
    .AllIndices()
    ...
)
```

Or if you want to search one index (thats not the default index)

```cs
client.Search<MyObject>(s=>s.
    .Index("Index_A")
    ...
)
```

Remember since elasticsearch 19.8 you can also specify wildcards on index names

```cs
client.Search<MyObject>(s=>s
    .Index("Index_*")
    ...
)
```

As for your [indices_query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/indices-query/)

```cs
client.Search<MyObject>(s=>s
    .AllIndices()
    .Query(q=>q
        .Indices(i=>i
            .Indices(new [] { "INDEX_A", "INDEX_B"})
            .Query(iq=>iq.Term("FIELD","VALUE"))
            .NoMatchQuery(iq=>iq.Term("FIELD", "VALUE"))
        )
    )
);
```

**UPDATE**

These tests show off how you can make C#'s covariance work for you:

https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest.Tests.Integration/Search/SubClassSupport/SubClassSupportTests.cs

In your case if all the types are not subclasses of a shared base you can still use 'object'

i.e:

```cs
 .Search<object>(s=>s
      .Types(typeof(Product),typeof(Category),typeof(Manufacturer))
      .Query(...)
 );
```

This will search on `/yourdefaultindex/products,categories,manufacturers/_search` and setup a default `ConcreteTypeSelector` that understands what type each returned document is.

Using `ConcreteTypeSelector(Func<dynamic, Hit<dynamic>, Type>)` you can manually return a type based on some json value (on dynamic) or on the hit metadata.

Comment: Hello Martijn, thanks for your reply! The way to query against different indices I already figured out. The main problem I currently face is that I have **different document types with different structure** stored in die indices like Books, Cars, etc. I mean your example is:

client.Search<MyObject>
 
MyObject would be in my case something more generic because I wanna retrieve Books, Cars, etc with one query. I tried with generic type but without success.

Comment: The only way I got documents back was by using client.Search(query). I also added MapTypeIndices to the connection settings (…). Could you please give an example to accomplish something like 

           `var results = Client.Search<?????????????????>(s => s
                       .Indices(new[] { “Book-index", "Car-index" })
                       .Size(200)
                       .MatchAll()
               );`
Or do you recommend another approach? Highly appreciate your effort!

Comment: Update: Currently I'm using the base class of Books, Cars etc but it isn't a clean solution. `client.Search<BASECLASS>`

Comment: @Neil NEST should have you covered here too, see my updated answer.

Comment: @Martjin, thank you very much - works like a charme! I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @Martjin This example doesn't work for me. Has this .Types interface gone away?

Comment: its now `.Type` see also: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/docs/asciidoc/ClientConcepts/HighLevel/CovariantHits/CovariantSearchResults.doc.asciidoc

Comment: dude the github link do not work anymore , can you provide a new version of it,