# DocumentExists() fails when a wildcard is used in its Type

Tags: nest, elasticsearch

The problem also exists for Update() using a Type wildcard, but I found that DocumentExists() does the same thing, so I've distilled the issue down here:

This works...

```
var docExists = client.DocumentExists<object>(d => d
    .Index(indexname)
    .Id(myId)
    .Type("Abcdef"));
```

but this fails...

```
var docExists = client.DocumentExists<object>(d => d
    .Index(indexname)
    .Id(myId)
    .Type("Abc*"));
```

It also fails if I omit the Type altogether.
Anyone know how to make this work? (Even if it worked regardless of the type of the document would be fine for my purpose.)

Comment: btw: By "fails", I mean its Exists property is set to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to specify wildcard in type name, but you can do a trick.

You can query your index for documents with specific id and use prefix filter to narrow down search on certain types.

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
    .Type(string.Empty)
    .Query(q => q.Term("id", 1))
    .Filter(f => f.Prefix("_type", "type")));
```

Here is the full example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var indexName = "sampleindex";

        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri).SetDefaultIndex(indexName).EnableTrace();
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        client.DeleteIndex(descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName));

        client.CreateIndex(descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName));

        client.Index(new Type1 {Id = 1, Name = "Name1"}, descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName));
        client.Index(new Type1 {Id = 11, Name = "Name2"}, descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName));
        client.Index(new Type2 {Id = 1, City = "City1"}, descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName));
        client.Index(new Type2 {Id = 11, City = "City2"}, descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName));
        client.Index(new OtherType2 {Id = 1}, descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName));

        client.Refresh();

        var searchResponse = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
            .Type(string.Empty)
            .Query(q => q.Term("id", 1))
            .Filter(f => f.Prefix("_type", "type")));

        var objects = searchResponse.Documents.ToList();
    }
}

class Type1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Type2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

class OtherType2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Don't know much about your big picture, but maybe you can change your solution to use indexes instead of types? You can put wildcard in the index names. [Take a look.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235039/nest-how-to-query-against-multiple-indices-and-handle-different-subclasses-doc/16294403#16294403)

Comment: What does the .Type(string.Empy) indicate?

Comment: I just wanted to omit type information in request to elasticsearch.