# Checking if a document exists in index using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, nest2

I'm reindexing my index, but I've encountered a problem whenever I try to delete a non-existing document, so I need to check if the document already exists.

The approach is just explained in the [elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-exists.html).

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565607/documentexists-fails-when-a-wildcard-is-used-in-its-type) with some interesting code, which I already tried

```
var docExists = client.DocumentExists<object>(d => d
    .Index(indexname)
    .Id(myId)
    .Type("Abcdef"));
```

But the compiler is giving an error

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Nest.DocumentPath<object>' because it's not a delegate type

I suppose my error comes because the question refers to NEST 1.x and I'm using NEST 2.x.

I know I can do a simple query, but I want to know if there is a direct way like ES [doc-exists](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-exists.html).

Thanks

Comment: What version of Nest are you using?

Comment: @bittusarkar Elasticsearch 2.0.0, Nest 2.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signature of `DocumentExists` changed a little bit in NEST 2.x.

Right now it looks like:

```
public IExistsResponse DocumentExists<T>(DocumentPath<T> document, Func<DocumentExistsDescriptor<T>, IDocumentExistsRequest> selector = null) where T : class
```

Your example could be expressed as follows

```
client.DocumentExists<Document>(myId, d => d
    .Index(indexname)
    .Type("Abcdef"));
```

If you are curious about `DocumentPath<T>` please read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/document-paths.html) great peace of NEST docs.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with this solution though `client.DocumentExists(new DocumentExistsRequest(indexName, type.Name, myId))`, as I couldn't use a generic method

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using

```
client.DocumentExists(new DocumentExistsRequest(indexName, type.Name, myId))
```

as I couldn't use the generic method `DocumentExists<T>(..)`