# NEST search through all available objects

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I've started writing a small utility for Elasticsearch using NEST and have no previous experience with Elastic API. Though I've tried to do my research I've stumbled with a few simple lines of code and can't understand how they supposed to work.

What I want to do: just look for an object with a specific field value. For example, I'll take modified Person class from  [Quick Start Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest-getting-started.html)

```
  public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FavoriteColor {get; set; }
        public string TimeAdded {get; set; }
    }
```

I have index `people_dd_mm_yyy`, so I can't set default index because it updates every day.

Also, I don't have a single idea which people will be in the index, so I just want to look through, let's say, people added today and find all people who love colour red.

```
        var p = new Person();
        var indexResponse = client.Index(p,s => s.Index("people_*"));
        var search = client.Search<Person>(s => s
        .From(0)
        .Size(10)
        .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
        .Field(f => f.FavoriteColor)
        .Query("Red"))));
```

Search won't find anything because all fields will be empty in search documents.
How do I just index all objects regardless of their content? Okay, I know I want all objects to have `FavoriteColor = Red`, so I can write

```
 var p = new Person() { FavoriteColor = "Red"};
```

but I have no idea what other fields will be, how do I make Elastic fill them in in response?

Seems I can't understand the idea of indexing and searching engine in Elastic.

I think I am trying to do [body search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html) but the example with this request on [github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net) also requires me to know everything about the object I want to search.

Answer (score 2):

First, If you want to search on multiple indexces you should specify it in the query like (check this great [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235039/nest-how-to-query-against-multiple-indices-and-handle-different-subclasses-doc))

```
client.Search<Person>(s => s
        .Index("people_*")...
```

Secondly, If you are interested in finding all persons where the favorit color is red, I would use Term instead of Match.
Term will make a filtering on Red while Match will make a Full Text Search and look for occurrences for Red in fields. 
If I would explain this as easy as possible I would compare them to SQL where Match is a SQL "LIKE" and Term is a SQL "=".
In large documents Term will most likely be the fastest alternative.

Proposed solution:

```
var search = client.Search<Person>(s => s
        .Index("people_*")
        .From(0)
        .Size(10)
        .Term(q => q
        .Field(p => p.FavoriteColor)
        .Value("Red")));
```

Comment: Also map `FavoriteColor` as a `keyword` data type

Comment: Hm, I have no Term() in the library for some reason, which is weird. Also, I was trying to write something similar in Kibana devtool window, just build a manual JSON request, and I failed to get any result yet, so seems it is rather a problem with my index and how I represent objects, than a NEST library usage